# F# Powerpack Documentation

Tags: documentation, f#, powerpack

I was wondering if someone can inform me of any decent documentation of F# Powerpack library. Thanks in advance.

Amir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know F# powerpack does not have official documentation. It had one before for F# version 1.9.6.x(something like that) hosted at Microsoft research(Not MSDN).

You can learn the usage of it from blog posts and books:

The [home page](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) of powerpack has a few examples.

The Expert F# 2.0 by Don Syme et. al actually has covered a lot of stuff in the PowerPack. E.g. matrix and vector in Chapter 10, some async library for web/network in Chapter 13, lexing and parsing in Chapter 16, and the theory behind the F# Linq in Chapter 9.

There should also be a lot of blog posts for F# PowerPack.

If you need to have a sense of what's really available, you'd like to go to the source code, especially the .fsi files containing the function prototypes.

Comment: Thanks for the nice book suggestion.

Comment: Here is the old documentation for 1.9.6: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/namespaces.html

Comment: Hi @Yin Zhu - I ask a question over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50794/whats-new-in-expert-f-2-0 about Expert F# 2.0, thought you might be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no comprehensive documentation for F# PowerPack at the moment. The [project homepage](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) contains some very basic information with a few links, but you'll probably have to rely on your favorite search engine and blogs.

What particular part of PowerPack are you interested in?

*Aside, I have a few (almost ready) articles about numerical functionality in PowerPack, so if that's what you're looking for, I can send you a draft (before I finally get to publish them).*

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Tomas. I think I am interested in all parts of it. Since it's small and easy to learn tool and contains basic tools that come in handy in all aspects of the project that I am working on. The numerical functionality in particular is very interesting for me right now. Because the project that I am working on, requires consecutive multiplication of huge matrices. So if you think that it gives more power to use this functionality, I will be grateful if you can share your draft with me. Should I give you my email address or will send a link here? sorry I'm a noob here!

Comment: @amirmonshi: Send me an email (tomas@tomasp.net). The numeric support in F# PowerPack is quite basic - for larger scale projects, you could consider open-source project Math.NET http://www.mathdotnet.com/ or some commercial library (e.g. Extreme Optimizations has some F# examples: http://www.extremeoptimization.com/)

Comment: I also suggest Sho library by Microsoft Research. BTW, I recommended my blog if you are doing numerical stuff in F#: http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/.